# Sed replace nth column of multiple tsv files without header

Tags: awk, sed

Here are multiple tsv files, where I want to add 'XX' characters only in the second column (everywhere except in the header) and save it to this same file.

Input:

```
$ls
file1.tsv file2.tsv file3.tsv

$head -n 4 file1.tsv
a   b   c
James England  25
Brian France   41
Maria France   18
```

Ouptut wanted:

```
a   b   c
James X1_England  25
Brian X1_France   41
Maria X1_France   18
```

I tried this, but the result is not kept in the file, and a simple redirection won't work:

```
   # this works, but doesn't save the changes 
    i=1
    for f in *tsv
      do awk '{if (NR!=1) print $2}’ $f | sed "s|^|X${i}_|" 
      i=$((i+1))
    done

    # adding '-i' option to sed: this throws an error but would be perfect (sed no input files error)
    i=1
    for f in *tsv
      do awk '{if (NR!=1) print $2}’ $f | sed -i "s|^|T${i}_|" 
      i=$((i+1))
    done
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWK solution:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR!=1 { $2 = "X1_" $2 } 1' file1.tsv
```

Input:

```
a   b       c
James       England 25
Brian       France  41
Maria       France  18
```

Output:

```
a   b       c
James       X1_England      25
Brian       X1_France       41
Maria       X1_France       18
```

Comment: You should mention thats GNU awk only for `-i inplace`.

Comment: Indeed, for other versions can use `awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR!=1 { $2 = "X1_" $2 } 1' file1.tsv > file1.tmp && mv file1.tmp file1.tsv`

Answer (score 2):

The second column is particularly easy because you simply replace the first occurrence of the separator.

```
for file in *.tsv; do
    sed -i '2,$s/\t/\tX1_/' "$file"
done
```

If your `sed` doesn't recognize the symbol `\t`, use a literal tab (in many shells, you type it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>.) On *BSD (and hence MacOS) you need `-i ''`